# To identify warning status of service in linux

Tags: linux

i would like to know, how to find out the services is in warning status where to find in linux?

ps -ef | grep -q process id; echo $? showing the output as 0 .

how to find the status for the warning status on linux

Comment: What is a "warning status"?. It seems you are trying to see if specific process ids are running. Normally to check if services are up you use `systemctl status {service_name}`, or `service [service_name} status`, depending on the service architecture used.

Comment: Hi,

we have a webpage and it shows services are shown below

running (tick) symbol
stopped (X) symbol
warning (!) symbol

in the webpage, if the service shows as (!) warning

we are trying to fetch the service status from server end as below 

ps -ef | grep -q process id; echo $? showing the output as 0 for both running and warning.

how to fetch the warning status from server end.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of "ps -ef XXXX", it will list the grep command itself:

```
>> ps -ef | grep XXXX
me        4138   712  0 17:30 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto XXXX
```

So it always finds your processid even though this is not in the processid column. You have to extract the PID column before you filter with `grep`, for instance with `awk`:

```
ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | grep XXXX ; echo $?
```

Comment: Hi,

we have a webpage and it shows services are shown below

running (tick) symbol
stopped (X) symbol
warning (!) symbol

in the webpage, if the service shows as (!) warning

we are trying to fetch the service status from server end as below 

ps -ef | grep -q process id; echo $? showing the output as 0 for both running and warning.

how to fetch the warning status from server end.

Comment: My answer tells you why you will always get $!==0 the way you do it,and what you can do to change that.

Comment: Normally, we used to see the service status as shown below

service <service name> status--> it will show you the service is in running or stopped(not showing warning status)

I would like to know the service warning status, so i have tried to $?==0 command.

So please tell me how to know the service warning status and we have anything for that.

Comment: Did you even try the last command in my answer (`ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | grep {insert_pid_here} ; echo $?`)

Comment: yes tried the command and its output like
(ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | grep {insert_pid_here} ; echo $?
<Process iD>
0